# How to use Lucene FastVectorHighlighter on multiple fields?

Tags: lucene, lucene-highlighter

I've got a basic search working, and I'm highlighting using `FastVectorHighlighter`.  When you ask the highlighter for a "best fragment" you have a few overloads of `getBestFragment(s)` to choose from, [documented here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/highlighter/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/FastVectorHighlighter.html).  I'm now using the simplest one, like this:

```
highlightedText = highlighter.getBestFragment(fieldQuery, searcher.getIndexReader(), 
     scoreDoc.doc, "description", 100)
```

So I'm highlighting the match from the "description" field.  My query however searches another field, "notes".  How do I include that in the highlighting?  There is an overload that takes a `Set<String> matchedFields` and one `String storedField`, but I don't understand the docs. The doc for the method says:

> it is advisable that all matchedFields share the same source as storedField or are at least a prefix of it.

What does that mean? How do I index the "notes" and "description" Strings, and what do I pass for `matchedFields` and `storedField`?

Answer (score 0):

That call, I believe, is intended to highlight against multiple indexed forms of the same content.  That is, if you have one stored full-text content field, but you have indexed it in a number of different ways to expand how you can search it.  Perhaps you have one indexed field that uses standard analysis, another with language-specific stemming, another that uses ngrams, and another indexing metaphones.

If you want to highlight two different stored fields, two calls to `getBestFragment` would be called for.  Or you could use a different highlighter that allows multiple stored fields to be highlighted at the same time, [`PostingsHighlighter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/postingshighlight/PostingsHighlighter.html), for instance.